# Netlogo: Obtaining a third list from the relation of other two lists

Tags: netlogo

I want to extract a third list from the relation of two previous lists. Here is the example:

I have a process in NetLogo that outputs a list of 0 and 1, let's call it List_A:

```
let List_A [0 1 0 1 1 ]
```

The positions of 0 and 1 always vary depending on several factors that are not relevant to this question.

There is a second list related to List_A called List_B:

```
let List_B [“residential” “industrial” “commercial” “farmland” “preservation”]
```

The positions of this list items never vary.

The third list I want to obtain is items of List_B that have a position corresponding to positions in items of List_A that have a value of 1. So, according to the previous examples, this would be a list made of [“industrial” “farmland” “preservation”], because “residential” and and “commercial” would have position that corresponds to a value of 0 and thus removed from the list.

Made some progress with this code that outputs a list of the positions of List_A of items that have value 1:

```
to-report comp-positions
report filter [ i -> item i List_A = 1 ] 
n-values (length List_A) [ i -> i ] 
end
```

but don’t know how to apply it to List_B to obtain the third list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, three more ways:

```
print map last filter [ p -> first p = 1 ] (map list List_A List_B)

print reduce sentence (map [ [a b] -> item a (list [] b) ] List_A List_B)

print reduce [ [acc val] ->
  ifelse-value (first val = 1) [ lput last val acc ] [ acc ]
] fput [] (map list List_A List_B)
```

Comment: An equivalent to WL's [Nothing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a one-step way, but maybe use a combination of `map` and `filter`? A `map` using `ifelse-value` can produce a list of the zeroes and "List_B" items, then filter to drop the zeroes:

```
to filter-map
  let List_A [0 1 0 1 1 ]
  let List_B [ "residential" "industrial" "commercial" "farmland" "preservation"]

  print filter [ i -> i != 0 ] ( map [ [ a b ] -> ifelse-value (a = 1) [b] [0] ] List_A List_B)
end
```